# year n+1 < year n in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a problem with excel not recognizing the years properly.

Here is my code

```
' Sort value
max = Sheets("booking").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:H" & max).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D" & max) _
, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & max) _
, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:H" & max)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

' mark past booking in italic and in red if not validated
For L = 2 To max
    If Format(CDate(booking.Cells(L, 5).Value), "dd-mm-yy") < Format(CDate(cells(1,10).value), "dd-mm-yy") Then
        booking.Cells(L, 5).EntireRow.Font.Italic = True
            If booking.Cells(L, 5).Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                booking.Cells(L, 5).EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
            Else
                booking.Cells(L, 5).EntireRow.Font.Color = vbBlack
            End If
    End If
Next L
```

The column D is full of date formated `dd-mm-yy`
The cell `(1,10) = now()`

When the code needs to sort the orders by date : np, it puts the 2014 orders in front of the 2013 orders

BUT

when the code applies the italic format for the dates < now, the 2014 orders are considered as past and the code put them in italic

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You shouldn't use "Format" to compare dates. You just don't have to and it probably messes all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that in the For loop you are comparing the dates as strings, so I am not surprised that you get different results. You should change

```
If Format(CDate(booking.Cells(L, 5).Value), "dd-mm-yy") < Format(CDate(cells(1,10).value), "dd-mm-yy") Then
```

to

```
If booking.Cells(L, 5).Value < booking.Cells(1,10) Then
```

on unrelated note, what is the value of variable `cells` in the second part of your `If` statement? Did you forget to precede it with `booking.`?

Comment: Thx for your help but actually ... well I'm almost ashamed to admit it but my error was coming from deleting the lines i was using for test without thinking that the format (italic and color) was ofc not reseted !!!!! Now that i put all line to normal format, MIRACLE it's working -.- !! Thx anyway for your help !!